# как сделать Attach оружия, которое симулирует физику, к сокету Игрока

Tags: unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine, unreal-engine-5, blueprint

Я хочу чтобы когда у оружия нет владельца,оно каталось по полу. Когда у него появляется владелец (игрок) оно становится статичным и лежит в сокете на руке. И когда его выбрасываешь оно снова катается по полу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае нужно сделать вот что:
При дропе оружия, выключать колизию у оружия, а именно:
Зайти в физический ресурс, или отключать кодом, и выключить:

> Simulation Generates Hit Events

При подборе оружия, снова его включать.